# Breaking with a divider if more than one inside foreach

Tags: php

`$linkPairs` returns the following:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'Test|https://www.test2.com' (length=26)
  1 => string 'Test2|http://www.test2.com/' (length=27)
```

How would I be successful on breaking the links using a divider as this: `Test | Test2` .. the format that I'm getting now is `TestTest2`.

So I have the following code:

```
$linkPairs = explode(",", $atts['link']); // separate the pairs
$output = '';

$output .= '<li class="slide">
        <p><img src="' . esc_url($atts['image']) . '" alt="" /></p>
        <p>'. $atts['headline'] .'</p>
        <p>'. $atts['body'] .'</p>';

foreach($linkPairs as $linkPair) {
    $pair = explode("|", $linkPair); // separate the title and url
    $output .= '<a href="' . $pair[1] . '" target="_blank">' . $pair[0] . '</a>';
}

$output .= '</li>';
```

Comment: where do you expect test|test2 to appear its not quite clear?

Comment: @waanofii.tech, so I'm already getting the output for the a tag, just shortening the code to make it more readable.

Comment: you said the output you are getting is TestTest2 from which line is it that you are getting this i don't see it in your code?

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what the problem is and how it differs from what you have.

Comment: The $output returns everything, but inside the foreach.. the $output .= <a href=""> loops through and returns the 2 links

Comment: @Quasipickle, the way that I'm currently getting the output is Test1Test2 (These are two separate links) .. I want it to check if there is more than one link in the foreach and output the links with a seperator such as Link1 | Link2.

Comment: i just run your code on localhost and this is what i got `<a href="https://www.test2.com" target="_blank">Test</a><a href="https://www.test2.com" target="_blank">Test2</a></li>` only for the link part i believe you want them to be included into the different `<li>` tag if that's is the case tell me. i will rewrite. or you just wanted to put | between the links if you just want to add `|` you can add | right after closing tag of anchor `</a>.

Comment: try adding a ```\n```. i.e. ```. '</a>\n'```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method to do it, would be add the links to an array, and [`implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) them with what you wish to have separate them:

```
$output .= '<li class="slide">
        <p><img src="' . esc_url($atts['image']) . '" alt="" /></p>
        <p>'. $atts['headline'] .'</p>
        <p>'. $atts['body'] .'</p>';

$hrefs = array();// define and clean for this item
foreach($linkPairs as $linkPair) {
    $pair = explode("|", $linkPair); // separate the title and url
    $hrefs[] = '<a href="' . $pair[1] . '" target="_blank">' . $pair[0] . '</a>';
}
$output .= implode(' | ',$hrefs);// implode them here

$output .= '</li>';
```

The imploded pipe, is not to be confused with the original pipe used in the raw data you work with. You mentioned you wanted to space your hrefs with a pipe, so that is the example above.

Comment: Thanks so much @IncredibleHat - This works! Now I can learn from this and I wasn't aware that I can define an array and then pass that array to output. Works just as expected.

Comment: Well, you pass that array to output *through* `implode` which turns it into a string (with spacers).

Answer (score 0):

Update your foreach to add the divider, then `rtrim()` the last one

```php
$divider = ' | ';
foreach($linkPairs as $linkPair) {
    $pair = explode("|", $linkPair); // separate the title and url
    $output .= '<a href="' . $pair[1] . '" target="_blank">' . $pair[0] . '</a>'.$divider;
}
$output = rtrim($output,$divider);
```

Answer (score 0):

since it's good to know all possible ways you can also do the following count number of elements inthe `linkPairs` array then track the array pointer location to know the last link so that you don't add `|` to the last entry. I have explained everything i added in comment infront of the line.

```
    $linkPairs = explode(",", $atts); // separate the pairs
    $output = '';
    $output .= '<li class="slide">
            <p><img src="' . esc_url($atts['image']) . '" alt="" /></p>
            <p>'. $atts['headline'] .'</p>
            <p>'. $atts['body'] .'</p>';
    $li=count($linkPairs);//number of element of array
    $i=1;//track the current location of array_pointer
    foreach($linkPairs as $linkPair) {
        if($i!=$li){
            $symbol="|";//add | if the link is not the last link
        }
        else {
            $symbol="";//add nothing if the link is the last link
        }
        $pair = explode("|", $linkPair); // separate the title and url
        $output .= '<a href="' . $pair[1] . '" target="_blank">' . $pair[0] . '</a>'.$symbol;//$symbol is used to add | to the link
        $i++;
    }
    $output .= '</li>';
```